# How to save variables to a file

Tags: php, file

```
$files = array("post", "name", "date");

$post = $_POST["comment"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$date = date("H:i F j");

foreach ($files as $x) {
    $file = fopen("db/$x.txt", "a");
    $x = "$" . $x;
    fwrite($file, $x);
    fclose($file);
}
```

Trying to put values of `$post, $name` and `$date` into post.txt, name.txt and date.txt files respectively, but it puts literals `"$post"` into post.txt and so forth. Please help!

Comment: Just a thought: you might want to take a look at DB-Systems, for what you are doing. E.g. sqlight could help you storing your stuff.

Comment: Assosiative arrays do work, but sgtBOSE's method is a little more efficient. But anyways thanks everyone who helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `variable of variable` -

```
foreach ($files as $x) {
    $file = fopen("db/$x.txt", "a");
    $x = $$x;
    fwrite($file, $x);
    fclose($file);
}
```

> A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable.

You will get the details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use array instead, it's the right choice.

```
$values = array(
    'comment' => $_POST["comment"],
    'name' => $_POST["name"],
    'date' => date("H:i F j")
);

foreach ($values as $x) {
    $file = fopen("db/$x.txt", "a");
    fwrite($file, $x);
    fclose($file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using $x = "$".$x which doesn't give you the values you want.
Try this instead:

```
$files = [
    'comment' => $_POST['comment'],
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'date' => date('H:i F j')
];

foreach($files as $name => $value) {
    $file = fopen("db/$name.txt", "a");
    fwrite($file,$value);
}
```